# Linux: add command to another command in bashrc

Tags: linux, bash

I run a lot of commands(unit tests) that take a long time to finish.  Is there a way to alter my .bashrc to add a 'beep' to the end of every command so I don't have to remember to add it myself?

ex:
%phpunit yadayada ; beep

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contents of `PROMPT_COMMAND` is executed before every prompt. You can therefore cause a beep after every command with

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='beep'
```

To just beep after one specific command, you can override it with a function:

```
phpunit() {
  command phpunit "$@"
  beep
}
```

It's also prudent to preserve phpunit's exit code, so that you can still do things like `phpunit .. && doStuff` to only doStuff when the tests pass:

```
phpunit() {
  command phpunit "$@"
  local r=$?
  beep
  return $r
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty certain that it's not possible for every command, but you could create an alias to achieve this (using ping as the example)

```
#!/bin/bash
ping () { command ping "$@"; beep; }
```

[Edit:] **that other guy**'s solution is much better, i've adapted mine...